# Python tkinter grid layout mixed up

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, grid-layout

I'm new to Python and therefore Tkinter. For a first small project I'm trying to create a program to write a CSV file. The program gets a filename on startup, checks the file for a header and creates dynamically the necessary number of entry fields.

To make it easier to continue it shows the last row entered.

Currently I'm halfway through and the last line and the correct number of entry widgets are shown. Unfortunately the layout is rubbish.

[Example](http://almandor.de/images/grid.png)

I've expected the labels to be in front of the entry widgets and the Quit button on the bottom.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import Tkinter as tk
import argparse
import time

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('filename', nargs=1, help="file to parse")
args = parser.parse_args()

filename = args.filename[0]


def get_headers(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        headers = f.readline()
    return(headers)


def file_len(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i, l


class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, headers, filename, last_line, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.filename = filename
        lastentry = self.createWidgets(self.filename, headers, last_line)
        # print lastentry
        # print(lastentry[0].get()) # Test
        # lastentry[0].delete(0,tk.END) # Test
        # lastentry[0].insert(0,"Test") # Test

    def createWidgets(self, filename, headers, last_line):
        headers = get_headers(filename).split(',')  # .decode('utf8')
        self.lastentry = []
        self.entryfield = []
        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="CSV Entry Tool").grid(columnspan=3, pady=(0,10))
        for x, y in enumerate(headers):
            self.create_label_widget(x, y)
        for x, y in enumerate(last_line):
            self.lastentry.append(self.create_lastentry_widget(x, y))
        for x in range(len(last_line)):
            self.entryfield.append(self.create_entry_widget(x))

        self.lastlineLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Last Entry: ").grid(row=2, column=1, padx=(10,10), pady=(0,15))
        self.entryLabel = tk.Label(self, text="New Entry: ").grid(row=3, column=1, padx=(10,10), pady=(0,15))

        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid(row=6, column=6)
        return self.lastentry


    def create_label_widget(self, x, y):
        new_widget = tk.Label(self.master, text=y).grid(row=1, column=x+1, padx=(10,10), pady=(0,15))
        return new_widget

    def create_entry_widget(self, x):
        new_widget = tk.Entry(self.master)
        new_widget.grid(row=3, column=x+1, padx=(10,10), pady=(0,15))
        return new_widget

    def create_lastentry_widget(self, x, y):
        new_widget = tk.Entry(self.master)
        new_widget.grid(row=2, column=x+1, padx=(10,10), pady=(0,15))
        new_widget.insert(1, y)
        new_widget.configure(state="readonly")
        return new_widget

headers = get_headers(filename).split(',')  # .decode('utf8')

print headers

# Check Filelengh and get back last line.
file_lengh, last_line = file_len(filename)
print("Einträge: ".decode('utf8')) + str(file_lengh)
last_line = last_line.split(',')
print last_line


app = Application(headers, filename, last_line)
app.master.title('Sample application')
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: BTW: code `var = Widget(...).grid(...)` assigns `None` to `var` because `grid()` returns `None` - so do it in two steps `var = Widget(...)` and `var.grid(...)` or skip variable if you don't need it - `Widget(...).grid(...)`

Comment: you create labels and button in `self` but other elements in `self.master` - so they can be in different widgets which have own grid.

Comment: BTW: use module `csv` to read csv files - now it reads incorrectly my file which has comma in text in one column - like `"(x,y)"`. It has also problem if text in one column has `\n` inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create labels and button in `self` but other elements in `self.master` - so they can be in different widgets which have own grid.

After changing `self.master` into `self` and `column=x+1` into `column=x+2` I got

[image]

I change also `var = Widget(...).grid(...)` into `var = Widget(...)` and `var.grid(...)`

You should use `csv` module to read data because correct csv row with 3 columns

```
 "a","b","(x,y)"
```

you read as 4 columns.

And you can have the same problem with `\n`

```
 "a","b","(x
 y)"
```

Your code reads this as 2 rows but it is correct one row.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import Tkinter as tk
import argparse
import time

# --- classes ---

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, headers, filename, last_line, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.filename = filename
        lastentry = self.createWidgets(self.filename, headers, last_line)
        # print lastentry
        # print(lastentry[0].get()) # Test
        # lastentry[0].delete(0,tk.END) # Test
        # lastentry[0].insert(0,"Test") # Test

    def createWidgets(self, filename, headers, last_line):
        headers = get_headers(filename).split(',')  # .decode('utf8')

        self.lastentry = []
        self.entryfield = []

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text="CSV Entry Tool")
        self.label.grid(columnspan=3, pady=(0,10))

        for x, y in enumerate(headers):
            self.create_label_widget(x, y)

        for x, y in enumerate(last_line):
            self.lastentry.append(self.create_lastentry_widget(x, y))

        for x in range(len(last_line)):
            self.entryfield.append(self.create_entry_widget(x))

        self.lastlineLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Last Entry: ")
        self.lastlineLabel.grid(row=2, column=1, padx=(10,10), pady=(0,15))

        self.entryLabel = tk.Label(self, text="New Entry: ")
        self.entryLabel.grid(row=3, column=1, padx=(10,10), pady=(0,15))

        self.quitButton = tk.Button(self, text='Quit', command=self.quit)
        self.quitButton.grid(row=6, column=4)

        return self.lastentry


    def create_label_widget(self, x, y):
        new_widget = tk.Label(self, text=y)
        new_widget.grid(row=1, column=x+2, padx=(10,10), pady=(0,15))
        return new_widget

    def create_entry_widget(self, x):
        new_widget = tk.Entry(self)
        new_widget.grid(row=3, column=x+2, padx=(10,10), pady=(0,15))
        return new_widget

    def create_lastentry_widget(self, x, y):
        new_widget = tk.Entry(self)
        new_widget.grid(row=2, column=x+2, padx=(10,10), pady=(0,15))
        new_widget.insert(1, y)
        new_widget.configure(state="readonly")
        return new_widget

# --- functions ---

def get_headers(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        headers = f.readline()
    return(headers)

def file_len(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        for i, l in enumerate(f):
            pass
    return i, l

# --- main ---

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('filename', nargs=1, help="file to parse")
args = parser.parse_args()

filename = args.filename[0]

headers = get_headers(filename).split(',')  # .decode('utf8')

print headers

# Check Filelengh and get back last line.
file_lengh, last_line = file_len(filename)
print("Eintrage: ".decode('utf8')) + str(file_lengh)
last_line = last_line.split(',')
print last_line

app = Application(headers, filename, last_line)
app.master.title('Sample application')
app.mainloop()
```